# iOS OpenGL Question

Tags: ios, opengl-es, unity-game-engine

I'm an intermediate iOS developer with a couple apps on the store with decent results, but I have an idea for a game. I even have some pretty spectacular ideas in mind for monetizing this game.

My problem is I don't know the first thing about OpenGL -- I'm reading the documentation and watching some videos, but that's a deep rabbit hole.

My question is: Am I better off rolling my own 3d engine, or using the SDKs already out there -- Unity, namely -- and how different should I expect those approaches to be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're making a game, you're almost never better off rolling your own renderer. Not unless there's something special about your game rendering that you need to do that engines cannot accomplish.

Oh, and we have a [site for game development questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

While making a game, if you actually want to learn something then you should go for your own 3d engine.
If you go for others engine then yes, may be you will face less difficulties but at the same time you have to go according to their boundaries and limitations. 
And OpenGL ES is an API used for rendering and graphics purposes.You need to learn OPenGL ES not whole OpenGL api. Its well documentation is available out there.
here's a [link] http://www.khronos.org/opengles/

Comment: "You need to learn OpenGL ES not whole OpenGL api"? They're not really different, ES leaves out only a few functionalities.

Comment: but it does not contain whole glut library.

Comment: GLUT is definitely not part of OpenGL (and neither complicated). It's just a GUI library. OpenGL is an API used for rendering and graphics purposed only (said in your own words), nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nicol. Your time and effort is probably better spent developing the game rather than developing, yet another, '3D engine'.

Take a look at the Unity tutorials. They'll give you an idea of the development process. 
http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/

> and how different should I expect those approaches to be?

Unity development is very different from OpenGL development. Unity is closer to an authoring environment.